# Quick sort algorithm with central pivot element not working

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm a newbie C-programmer and have been working on this algorithm for a long time. I'm very frustrated because I have not been able to get a correct non-decreasing sorted sequence.

All help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int swap(short* a, short fst , short scnd){
    short temp  = a[fst] ;
    a[fst]          = a[scnd] ;
    a[scnd]         = temp ;

    return 0 ;
}

int div(short* a ,short p,short middle ,short r){
    while( p < r ){
        if( p < middle ){       
            if( a[p]      > a[middle] ){
                swap(a ,p ,middle) ; 
            }
            p++ ; 
        }
        if( middle < r ){
            if( a[middle] > a[r] ){
                swap(a ,middle , r) ;      
            }         
            r-- ;
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}

int fast(short* a , short p , short r){
    if( p < r){
        int middle = (p+r)/2 ;
        div(a, p, middle ,r ) ;
        fast(a, p ,middle-1 ) ;
        fast(a ,middle+1 ,r);
    }
}

int main(){
    short n ,i ;
    scanf("%hd",&n);
    short a[n+1] ;
    for(i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ ){
        scanf("%hd",&a[i]);
    }

    fast(a ,1 ,n ) ;
    i=1;
    while(i<=n){
        printf("%hd " , a[i]);
        i++ ;
    }
    getch() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your program? Is it crashing? Is it producing the wrong output?  Can you give some example input?

Comment: it is not producing correct results ....it is not crashing...you can see the output at http://ideone.com/GzWkc

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in the div function itself, that didn't follow the QuickSort logic.
You could fin working code here [Quicksort algorithm](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/quicksort-algorithm-c-source-code.aspx)

I would recommend to copy-paste the code and get inspired by it's coding-standard too, including comments :)

Comment: i am trying a variation of Quick sort actually ....i want the middle index to have that element which we would get at that index after sorting all the elements... please help ...

Comment: @parallelis...i am trying a variation of Quick sort actually ....i want the middle index to have that element which we would get at that index after sorting all the elements... please help ...

Answer (score 0):

I would change your div function to return the resulting index of the partition.  That way in the fast() function you can recurse on both side of the partition point.  This cleans up the logic and should make it easy to test the div function in isolation and find the weak point in your logic (it's definitely in the div() function).

It looks like currently your code is assuming that the partition always happens in the middle, which is not always the case for quicksort (in fact that is one of the subtle points to quicksort).

Here is an example partition function:

```
// please forgive any C-syntax errors not my best language
// low and high indicate a segment of the array to partition
// returns the index between low and high which serves as
// the partition point
int partition(short a[], int low, int high){
  int partition = low;
  int pivot = high;  // sub-optimal when a is already sorted
  for(int i=low; i<high; i++){
    if(a[i] < a[pivot]){
      swap(&a[i], &a[partition]);
      partition++;
    }
  }
  // places the pivot into its final sorted position at partition
  swap(&a[partition], &a[pivot]);
  return partition;
}
```

This can be used recursively as follows

```
sort(short a[], int low, high){
  if(high-low > 0){
    int partition = partition(a, low, high);
    // recurse to left and right of partition
    sort(a, low, partition-1);
    sort(a, partition+1, high);
  }
}
```

Comment: i am trying a variation of Quick sort actually ....i want the middle index to have that element which we would get at that index after sorting all the elements... please help ...

Comment: then you are not doing quicksort at all, at a glance I don't think you can determine which item belongs in the median index quickly (without sorting).  Again quick sort works by recursive partitioning, which results in a sorted array.  The partition is not a full sort (which is what makes this step of the algorithm fast)... it only creates some point in the array where items to the left of the partition point are less and items to the right are greater than or equal to the partition point. If you are not implementing the classical quick sort you should state that in bold letters.

Answer (score 0):

one data seq:
index:1 2 3  4 5 6 7
data: 1 2 0 10 8 4 5
middle: (1 + 7) / 2 = 4
a[middle]=10
what do your function div want?

Comment: div function sets the correct element at pivot position what we would get after sorting at that index ....

Comment: @topcoder: you try to say it again from reading the code written by myself.

Comment: You need to try to simulate on paper.

Comment: i am trying a variation of Quick sort actually ....in every div function call,i want the middle index to have that element which we would get at that index after sorting all the elements